# Nvidia RTX 3060 Ti driver for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a newly **desktop PC** equipped with Intel i7 and RTX 3060 Ti. It gets stuck and stays frozen every time after installing the proprietary Nvidia driver via Software & Updates → additional drivers ( I choose: Nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-460 (proprietary, tested)).

Is there a specific Nvidia driver that supports RTX 3060 Ti in Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: Go to Software and Updates screen on your Ubuntu system. Click on Additional Drivers and if the GPU 3060 Ti is installed it should give you a list of options to choose from. If all else fails you can run X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video--nouveau (open source)

Comment: Still stuck with the driver issue on Ubuntu 22.04. Tried all the recommended drivers from the Additional Drivers app. Each of them has a issue and nothing is stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears [these steps](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) are the solution you are looking for

Comment: While this may be useful information, just a heads-up that link-only answers are [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413510/11810933) and typically even deleted by Moderators on Stack Exchange sites unless the answer is [edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1314567/edit) to provide more information.  It's best to include the relevant portions of the link, or at least a summary, in your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I would downvote this if I had enough points

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolved it by disabling the *IGD Multi-Monitor* setting in the motherboard's firmware.

Note that this means that you won't be able to use the integrated graphics video ports on the motherboard, just the video ports on your graphics card.