# Ubuntu 20.4 Asus Tuf Dash F15 Nvidia Driver Hung on Boot

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I have installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 20.4 on my band new Asus Tuf Dash F15 laptop. Then I went into the software update settings and switched the driver to nvidia-460 proprietary using the GUI. I apply the changes and restart and I get stuck at a boot loading screen. The error is `/dev/nvm1e0 clean: xxxblocks/xxx`.

Specs:
Nvidia RTX 36060 mobile
Intel i7
40gb ram
1tb storage

I have tried installing the nvidia drivers 4 different ways, according to the nvidia official installation guide and multiple medium forums. Every time I get the same problem and have to alt+shift+f2 my way into the terminal to `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` to be able to boot back in.

I've installed nvidia diver on ubuntu many other times according to the nvidia official docs and never ran into this error. I am concerned it may be hardware incompatibility at this point?

I've been trying for three days now and re-installed ubuntu multiple times, varying the partitions and installation methods. Everything is working fine until I try and switch to nvidia driver. I even tried some older and new driver versions and the nvidia cuda toolkit 10 and 11. Please help, thank you.

Comment: hi @Yume. have you checked this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311476/nvidia-rtx-3060-ti-driver-for-ubuntu-20-04 and this https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux?.

Comment: Also. There is another recommendation to set "intel_idle.max_cstate=1" in grub boot command line.

Comment: @jpbrain This is literally one of the methods I've already tried to install Nvidia driver, does not work. How do you set intel_idle.max_cstate=1?

Comment: you need to edit /etc/default/grub and add that text to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, and the update-grub. Also, Have you checked if there is a Bios update also?. I use a different ASUS TUF F15 (not dash), but do not have that problem.

Comment: @jpbrain did as you said, rebooted, then installed driver according to the link you gave, now I cant boot at all. It starts up like normal and then just stops after Started Daemon for power management. There is just that text, black screen, and blinking dash curser. ;[

Comment: Bad news. do you know how to go back to the old configuration?. Steps are: Boot from a ubuntu pendrive. Mount root partition, chroot to that partition, reverse line and update-grub.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problems with a machine with the same specs as yours attempting to boot a clean install of Ubuntu Studio 20.04. Worked fine until I installed the native Nvidia drivers.  Same symptoms with the a black screen after the Asus splash screen. I was able to fix the issue by doing the following steps (not sure all of these are needed, but it's what worked for me):

- Update the BIOS for the Tuf book to latest (version 309).
- Remove the Windows boot drive and install a 1 TB blank drive.
- Install PopOS 20.04 LTS using the installer with the Nvidia drivers.

I think that last step is the one that got it working.  I verified I have the proprietary Nvidia drivers installed (Driver Version: 465.31 ) on Pop OS 20.04 and it's booting correctly.